# I'am not able to find the getHeaders method in the HttpResponse Class documentation nor in the closeableHttpResponse class

Tags: java, httpresponse, apache-httpclient-4.x, closeablehttpresponse

I can not find documentation for this method despite there is many code examples on the internet that uses this method, someone can tell me please where to find it? there is also a method "getElements" that i can not find in java documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpMessage` is an interface that `CloseableHttpResponse` implements. That's where the `getHeaders` method comes from

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/CloseableHttpResponse.html